# GmailApi - search mails newer then minutes

Tags: java, email, gmail-api

Simple question:

**Is it possible to search for mails that are newer then, say, 5 minutes using GMailApi?**

The newer_then samples I found only have a day-resolution.

**Update**

I tried something like

```
mService.users().messages().list(user).setQ("after:2017/05/02 17:00:00").execute();
```

without any success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a timestamp as the `after` value:

1493761547 secs (2017/05/02 21:45)

5 mins is 300 sec

`.setQ()"after:1493761247"`

Comment: Just tested it, works perfectly. I already started to use the Date Header of each message to parse the time by myself. Your solution is much better. Thank you.